# What does the argument TRUE do in case_when( ) function?

Tags: r

I was learning R, and I was wondering what does the TRUE ~ "Other" do in this kind of code?

```
gapminder <- gapminder %>% 
  mutate(group = case_when(
    .$region %in% west ~ "West"  # assign the factor "West" for countries with region = west
    .$region %in% c("Eastern Asia", "South-Eastern Asia") ~ "East Asia"
    .$region %in% c("Carribbean", "Central America", "South America") ~  "Latin America"
    .$continent == "Africa" & .$region != "Northern Africa" ~ "Sub-Saharan Africa",
    TRUE ~ "Other"))
```

Comment: This is the default value. If all other choices are `FALSE`, the last one being `TRUE` will be selected.

Comment: It's the `case_when` variant of an `else` statement in an `if`-`else`-structure.

Answer (score 5):

Case_when is particularly useful inside mutate when you want to create a new variable that relies on a complex combination of existing

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

The TRUE specifies the default value when the other conditions are not met. So, in your example when region does not fall within the following regions:

- West
- Eastern Asia
- South-Eastern Asia
- Carribbean
- Central America
- South America

Or when continent is "Africa" & region is NOT "Nothern Africa". I would pay special attention here as it looks you are creating a new variable named region but you already have "Northern Africa" as a predefined region but not predefined in the code

THEN anything else would be classified as "Other" under the region column.